# Error when installing jenkins workflow plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-workflow

I'm trying to install the Jenkins workflow plugin into a Jenkins 1.641 installation. I have downloaded the latest version of the plugin (v1.12 - https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Workflow+Plugin). On trying to upload and install, I get this error:-

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to dynamically deploy this plugin
at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1383)
at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1161)
at
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:110)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to install workflow-aggregator plugin
at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:487)
at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1379)
... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Dependency workflow-basic-steps (1.12), workflow-scm-step (1.12), workflow-cps-global-lib (1.12), workflow-support (1.12), workflow-job (1.12), workflow-durable-task-step (1.12), workflow-cps (1.12), workflow-api (1.12), workflow-step-api (1.12) doesn't exist
at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:533)
at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:477)
... 6 more
```

Can anyone suggest the cause of the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install `Pipeline (formerly known as Workflow) 1.13` (or `Workflow Aggregator 1.12` if you want 1.12 instead of 1.13) from the update center, don't try to install it manually (or you would have to install all the dependencies manually, as pointed in the log: `Dependency workflow-basic-steps (1.12), workflow-scm-step (1.12), workflow-cps-global-lib (1.12), workflow-support (1.12), workflow-job (1.12), workflow-durable-task-step (1.12), workflow-cps (1.12), workflow-api (1.12), workflow-step-api (1.12) doesn't exist`)

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the Problem is, that workflow-aggregator is only one piece of the workflow and is depending on other plugin parts.

The Other parts are found here :

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Dependency workflow-basic-steps (1.12), workflow-scm-step (1.12), workflow-cps-global-lib (1.12), workflow-support (1.12), workflow-job (1.12), workflow-durable-task-step (1.12), workflow-cps (1.12), workflow-api (1.12), workflow-step-api (1.12) doesn't exist
```

The easy solution is to use the update center as suggested by amuniz.

If you develop in an regulated environment and need more control over installed plugins or need a reproducible environment, download all dependent plugins.

I didnt find a link on the workflow parts (the dependencys link to the same page), so you may work around that problem by using a download url of following patern:

```
updates.jenkins-ci.org/latest/<plugin-name>.hpi
```

Example:

```
updates.jenkins-ci.org/latest/workflow-step-api.hpi
```

Or if you need a special revision of the plugin use:

```
http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/<plugin-name>/<revision>/<plugin-name>.hpi
```

Example :

```
http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/workflow-step-api/1.12/workflow-step-api.hpi
```